Checkboxes in <lightning-record-form> not updating when clicked
I'm getting some strange behaviour when using a  with checkbox fields in an LWC. If i click on the actual checkbox, the  checkbox does not become checked. But it updates if I click on the label. How can i fix this so it updates when clicking on the actual checkbox?
HTML:
<lightning-record-form
        data-id="marketing"
        record-id={contact.Id}
        object-api-name="Contact"
        fields={marketingFields}
        density="compact"
        columns="2"
        mode="view"
        oncancel={handleCancelMarketing}
        onsuccess={handleSuccessMarketing}
>
</lightning-record-form>

<template lwc:if={showEditButtonMarketing}>
    <div class="fsCustomCSS" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <button data-id="marketing" style="padding: 12px 33px;" onclick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
    </div>
</template>

JS:
handleEdit(event) {
    let id = event.target.dataset.id; // id will be "marketing"

    if(id === 'myInfo') {
        let editForm = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="myInfo"]');
        editForm.mode = 'edit';
        this.showEditButtonMyInfo = false;
    } else if(id === 'marketing') {
        let editForm = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="marketing"]');
        editForm.mode = 'edit';
        this.showEditButtonMarketing = false;
    }
}


Tom can you explain in detail like what is the value of {marketingFields}.
Or further you can refer to this documentation lightning-record-form
